# Why does AJAX not stop page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

Can someone please help me out with AJAX in Django. I'm trying to create a simple form with 2 inputs and send it to my python backend without a page refresh. Here's my AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#seearch").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault()

      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/some/',
        data:{
          origin:$('#origin').val(),
          destination:$('#destination').val(),
          },
        success:function(){
          document.write("HelloWorld")

        }

      });
      return false;

    });
  });

</script>
```

Here's the code I used for my form:

```
<div style = " 
      width:0.01px; 
      height:0.01px; 
      position:relative; 
      top:-700px; 
      left:0px;">

      <div class="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center" >
        <form id="seearch">

          <input id="origin" class="button" name="origin" placeholder="Where from?" type="text"><div></div>
          <input id="destination" class="button" name="destination" placeholder="Where to?" type="text">
          <input class="button" name="navigate" type="submit" placeholder="navigate">
        </form>
      </div>

  </div>
```

The request sent to backend should be an AJAX request but it is almost as if the AJAX code is ignored by the form. When I click submit, it just simply submits the form and refreshes the page.
I've been struggling with this for almost 2 days, and it'd be a great help if something could help me figure where I've gone wrong. Thanks!

Comment: is that script tag code placed below the html for you posted?

Comment: Check is there is no Jquery errors in the console also

Comment: The problem is caused by your button type, please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your submit button is of type="submit" . So it will try to reload the page as per "html form property".

So you have 2 options :

1. Change the type="submit"  to type="button" . So the the form will not be submitted automatically.
   But issue with this solution is , your other form properties ,like required and other things will not work.
2. The more appropriate solution is :

   < form onsubmit = "mySubmitFunction(event) " >

   -your form elements -

   < /form >

JavaScript part :

```
function mySubmitFunction(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ------ ajax--------
}
```

Choose what option is proper for your issue.